# AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'is_staff'

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have customized user model, Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        account = self.model(username=username)

        account.set_password(password)
        account.is_stuff = False
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(username, password, **kwargs)
        account.is_admin = True
        account.is_staff = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    initialized = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    objects = AccountManager()
```

then when I try to get list of all users it throws `AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'is_staff'` .

```
class GetUserList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

Comment: You have not defined an `is_staff` field on your model. Did you intend to?

Comment: `is_staff` field is not necessary for my custom `AbstractUser` because I'm not using at all @DanielRoseman in that case what's option!

Comment: In your `create_user` you have a line `self.is_stuff=False` which I think should be `self.is_staff=False`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`IsAdminUser`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L55) calls [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) which is defined on django's auth user model. So if you have your own custom user model, you need to provide an implementation to this also

In django's `AbstractUser` class, it is a BooleanField, as you can see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L324)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use is_staff or is_admin, You can just create a is_staff property for your model.
Example :

```py
    
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    initialized = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    objects = AccountManager()
```

That way you can do use your custom permissions without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked by adding these two in models

```
 is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then in the Manager

```
def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

This worked in Django 3.

 I have written a bit detailed post on this on [Dev.to](https://dev.to/theshubhagrwl/custom-user-model-in-django-3-32k7)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem after defining own permission:

```
class IsAdminUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_admin
```

Then

```
class GetUserList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

Comment: If you decide to create your own `IsAdminUser`, you may want to just `return request.user.is_admin` since as it stands, nothing is returned if the user isn't an admin which may result in unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sayse and @Daniel pointed out, you can solve this issue by adding the `is_staff` field to your custom user model:

```
is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'),default=False)
```

(That worked for me)